# SyntaxError : Unexpected POST_IF error

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

```
options = {
    host : 'http://localhost:8080'
    port : 8080
    path : '.frameset?__report=stock_report.rptdesign'
}

http.get(options , (res) ->
    console.log "Got response : " + res.statusCode
    res.on 'data' , (chunk) ->
        console.log "BODY : " + chunk
    ).on 'error' , (e) ->
    console.log "Got error : " + e.message
```

I want to sent http request for tomcat server in nodejs.
But Unexpected POST_IF error occur.
Why?

Comment: That is a CoffeeScript error message, but the code you have here compiles just fine.  Is there other code you didn't show?

Answer (score 3):

If you combine tabs with spaces for indentation, or use wrong indentation then coffeescript gives Unexpected POST_IF error. Solutions:

-- Make sure you're using only tab or space for indentation
-- If you're in Intellij Idea, Code -> Reformat Code (it tries to put indents correctly)